# Incorect SWF stage dimensions

Tags: html, flash

I need to have a swf file that fills the entire html page. But sadly I fail to make it work as intended. Even thought the SWF does indeed fill the entire page, it's dimensions are shown wrong. here is what I am talking about: http://tinypic.com/r/w7k75i/6

As you can see, the swf is at the end of the window, but the dimension is 1024x768 (the text at the bottom left corner) and the "stage resize" event was never triggered (0- the last number). This works perfectly when oppening the swf on my PC, but not when embeded in an html page.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

UPDATE: forgot to mention, I embed it like this: swfobject.embedSWF("flash.swf", "content", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0");

Answer (score 0):

You are probably embedding it wrong. Use [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to save yourself a lot of pain.

Try setting the height width to 100% and the div containing it.

```
swfobject.embedSWF(swfUrl, id, width, height, ...)
```

Comment: That is exactly how I embed it. Added in the original post.